# Struggling with modern texts involving algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question

I am reading some books which require a basic understanding of algebraic geometry. Most of them were published after 1960s, so the language of schemes was quite mature. However, it seems that many authors made a choice to only work with either schemes or classical varieties. For example, many mathematicians, influenced by Grothendieck, wrote their texts with strictly scheme-theoretic languages. Yet some very new textbooks only rely on the pre-Grothendieck notion of classical varieties. Another (in my opinion quite bizarre) approach is to use the notations from scheme theory while referring to notions in classical algebraic geometry. For instance, I saw an author denoted the space of maximal ideals by $\operatorname{Spec}$.

It came to a point that, as someone who has basic (but definitely insufficient) knowledge of both approaches, I can no longer distinguish if an author is referring to classical varieties or certain types of schemes of finite type over some field when I see the term "variety". Some texts rarely speak about the algebro-geometric nature of certain objects, so I could never infer the correct answer from the defs or proofs, which is unfortunate for me. Indeed, there is an equivalence of categories, but I sometimes really struggle with the texts' ambiguity.

One example I could accurately recall is texts about algebraic groups. When I see $\mathbb G_m$ I don't know if it's $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,x^{-1}]$ or just $k^\times$. Indeed, when an author does not provide an explicit definition, usually the distinction does not matter, or for each result regarding one of them, there is an equivalent for the other. Yet, the difference still matters to beginners like me because there might be different constructions based on each of the notions. For example, the Lie algebras of these groups.

Is there a way I could learn to overcome this struggle? Or are there some texts I could read to improve my understanding so that I would be able to distinguish the two cases immediately? Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it would be better to take the point of view that, say, $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the real thing and $\operatorname{Spec} k [x, x^{-1}]$ and $k^\times$ are just its shadows. Sometimes it is more convenient to use one formalism and sometimes it is more convenient to use another. (For example, if $k$ is algebraically closed, the classical picture is sufficient for most purposes. Not so if $k$ is not algebraically closed, let alone if $k$ is not a field...)